# How can I check if all the elements of a vector are within another vector in Eigen c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, eigen3

How can I check if all the elements of a vector are within another vector in Eigen c++? Or in other terms, How can I check that a vector is included in another, or is a subset of another vector in Eigen C++?

i.e.

If

```
Eigen::Matrix<Index, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  activeset <<0,1,2,3,4,5; 

Eigen::Matrix<Index, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  detectedset <<0,1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

Then activeset is included in detected set

However if

```
Eigen::Matrix<Index, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  activeset <<0,1,2,3,4,5; 

Eigen::Matrix<Index, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  detectedset <<0,1,2,3,5,6,7;
```

Then activeset is not included in detectedset, since  detectedset is missing the 4 which is inside activeset.

Is there a function in eigen c++ that can do that? Or how can we do it?

Comment: do the vectors contain unique entries and are they sorted? It is the case in your example

Comment: Eigen is a library for linear algebra focusing on, apart from the basic matrix and vector types, operations on these types as well as numerical solvers. It does not, however, cover set theory or offer a set type, so you would have to write your own `isSubset()` function if you want to be able view your matrices as a representation of a set collection of (possibly degenerated) numbers onto which you want to apply general set theory.

Comment: @idclev463035818 they are unique yes, but not surely sorted, however i think i can sort them, if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

With the development branch of Eigen (and the upcoming 3.4 version) you can access Eigen objects using iterators which are compatible to `std` algorithms, e.g., you can simply write:

```
std::includes(detectedset.begin(), detectedset.end(), activeset.begin(), activeset.end())
```

Full working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/kguGjW.

Note that [`std::include`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/includes/) requires both ranges to be sorted (which you can do with `std::sort`, if needed). Also note that for this purpose there is not much benefit to use `Eigen::Matrix<Index, Dynamic, 1>` instead of simply `std::vector<Eigen::Index>` (though maybe you have reasons outside this question to use `Eigen::Matrix` here).